# Do all commands sent to Redis using multi and pipeline make separate IO calls?

Tags: redis, ioredis

I have to run multiple commands in Redis from one of my microservices. But if I nest it one inside the other, it will make a separate IO operation to the Redis server for each command. Also, it looks nasty. So I am exploring `multi` and `pipeline` implementations in `ioredis` library. It looks something like this,

```
redis.multi()
  .set("stack", "overflow")
  .get("stack")
  .exec((err, results) => {
    // results === [[null, 'OK'], [null, 'bar']]
  });
```

Although it looks cleaner, I am unable to find out if the commands make separate IO calls to the servers or are sent all at once. How can I find out?